# In Srednicki's quantum field theory, page 71. Why is $Z_1 = W_1$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, notation, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, partition-function

Srednicki defines here: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0409035  on p.71

a "Z1", which is $exp(iW_1)$ where $iW_1$ is the sum of all *connected* diagrams with sourceless                                                                              diagrams not included. He then states that $$<0|\varphi |0> = \frac 1 i \left. \frac \delta {\delta J(x)} Z_1(J) \right|_{J=0} = \left. \frac \delta {\delta J(x)} W_1(J) \right|_{J=0},$$ where he is calculating what would happen if we ignore counter terms.

All of a sudden it seems $Z_1=W_1$. Why is that? He then says that this expression is then the sum of all diagrams that have a single source, with the source removed. Where did the diagrams with multiple sources disappear all of a sudden?

Comment: arXiv:hep-th/0409035 is obsolete. A newer prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's because when we set J=0, all terms that still have a J go to 0. And in a disconnected diagram, if you only allowed to have one source, you can have only one non vacuum diagram. Indeed I was missing something obvious.